# Pegar data atual da máquina

Tags: java, data

Preciso que quando execute o código ele pegue a data atual do sistema e atribua a uma `Date`.

Exemplo:

```
Date x = new Date(now);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Date x = new Date();
```

O construtor padrão de `Date` cria o objeto `Date` com a data e hora atual do relógio do sistema, tal como informado pelo sistema operacional.

Answer (score 8):

Basta não passar nenhum parâmetro. Assim:

```
Date now = new Date();
```

Como pode ser visto [aqui](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Date.java#Date.%3Cinit%3E%28%29), isto é o mesmo que chamar o construtor passando o valor de `System.currentTimeMillis`:

```
Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

No entanto, a classe `java.util.Date` pode lhe apresentar problemas com fuso horário. Na maioria dos casos não queremos se preocupar se o Java está executando numa máquina no Brasil ou no Japão.

Portanto, se está usando Java 8, prefira a [nova API de data e hora](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) onde existe a classe [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
```